# Pass object with complex property with web service

Tags: .net, web-services, serialization

I have 2 classes:

```
    public class testClass1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public testClass2 testClass2Object { get; set; }
    }

    public class testClass2
    {
        public testClass2() { }

        public testClass2(int i) { TestProperty = i; }

        public int TestProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to return first class's object with `webMethod` :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public testClass1 testMethod()
    {
        testClass1 test = new testClass1();
        test.Name = "stackoverflow";
        test.testClass2Object = new testClass2(2);
        return test;
    }
```

but I don't get the values of `testClass2` property from `testClass1` object.

I tried `[Serializable]
        [XmlInclude(typeof(testClass2))]` annotations but nothing changed. Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `public testClass2(int i)` constructor? And what about if you change the declaration to `public testClass2(int testProperty )`? (I ask the second because I know the actual names of ctor parameters can affect JSON serialisation; not sure if it will affect other serialisation though).

Comment: @Matthew Watson Removed constructor and it works now thanks.

Comment: @Matthew Watson I cannot have constructor with parameter if I want to send it's object?

Answer (score 1):

If I run the code "as is" and invoke testMethod(), I get...

```
<testClass1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <Name>stackoverflow</Name>
     <testClass2Object>
          <TestProperty>2</TestProperty>
     </testClass2Object>
</testClass1>
```

Are you expecting something different? Maybe I'm missing something.

If this is part of a bigger project, maybe try putting just this code into a new project and seeing if it could be a setting or other configuration type of problem.

Comment: Ha! I didn't realize I had put a bounty on this question. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I run your code and the output was something I was expected. You
>   should use xml parse to get your data from testclass2.

**EDIT**

I recommend to use Web API instead of obsolete `ASMX`, which use SOAP to generate non-structured no-schema tons of XML in output.

Web-API has a fast and light-weight output and you can have both JSON and XML format as output. very robust!